# Java IBM MQ client MQ.Environment setting hostname to only ip adress not connecting, but setting to "localhost" works. Local docker deployment ibm-mq

Tags: java, docker, networking, ibm-mq, mq

I'm using the com.ibm.mq.allclient-9.3.3.1.jar.

I have a java test class, which tests the connection to a local docker IBM MQ container.
I set it up like this:

```
        openOptions = CMQC.MQOO_INQUIRE | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_AS_Q_DEF | MQConstants.MQOO_OUTPUT;
        MQEnvironment.hostname = "localhost";
        MQEnvironment.port = 1414;
        MQEnvironment.channel = "DEV.APP.SVRCONN";
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.USER_ID_PROPERTY, "app");
        MQEnvironment.properties.put(CMQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, CMQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES);

        String queueManagerName = "QM1";
        queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueManagerName);
```

This is working fine.

But when I want to connect to it via the IP of the docker container, it is failing:

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = 172.27.0.2;
```

Error logs:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2538'.
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:251)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:449)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:486)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:870)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:818)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:760)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:893)
    at app//company.test.EaCompanyUtilLibertyTest.init(EaCompanyUtilLibertyTest.java:44)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at app//org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptBeforeAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:70)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllMethods$13(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:412)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:410)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:216)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:85)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.2/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.2/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.disconnect()" because "company.test.EaCompanyUtilLibertyTest.queueManager" is null
        at company.test.EaCompanyUtilLibertyTest.closeQueueManager(EaCompanyUtilLibertyTest.java:50)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:728)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptLifecycleMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:128)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptAfterAllMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:118)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$15(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:440)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllMethods$16(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:438)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1092)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllMethods(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:438)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:232)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:85)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '172.27.0.2(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '/172.27.0.2:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Operation timed out],3=/172.27.0.2:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]],3=172.27.0.2(1414),4=,5=RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket]
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13670)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.access$100(RemoteFAP.java:13202)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1451)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1392)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:377)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:562)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:916)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:236)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2538;AMQ9204: Connection to host '/172.27.0.2:1414' rejected. [1=java.net.ConnectException[Operation timed out],3=/172.27.0.2:1414,4=TCP,5=Socket.connect]
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:931)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.protocolConnect(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1505)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:1014)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:691)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:283)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:170)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:128)
    at app//com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP$Connector.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:13402)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:579)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Net.java:568)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:588)
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:583)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$4.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1105)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection$4.run(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1097)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:318)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.connectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:1097)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteTCPConnection.bindAndConnectSocket(RemoteTCPConnection.java:837)
```

Can someone please help me why? And how to fix it?

Comment: Perhaps you can show us why you think that IP address is the one you should use. And also if you have it working already with localhost, why do you want to use the IP address instead?

Answer (score 0):

Is the queue manager's listener object configured to listen on the primary ethernet interface rather than the localhost loopback adapter? MQRC 2538 means MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE, so this is either a case of the queue manager not listening on the IP in question, or it's a network configuration error for the container itself.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` will be `127.0.0.1`, ie your machine - the docker host, and not the docker container.

`172.27.0.2` will most likely be your docker container, it will be listening on port 1414, but its network will be isolated. Other containers running on the same network will be able to see it, but your machine (docker host) won't.

To communicate with the docker container, a port mapping will have been created, so that network traffic directed at port 1414 on the docker host (your machine) is redirected to the appropriate network and to the container.

So you need to substitute `localhost` with the ip of your machine.